# Errors in Karaf upgrade from 4.2.0.M1 to 4.2.0.M2

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf

We were upgrading Karaf and in the transition from 4.2.0.M1 to 4.2.0.M2 we noticed several errors like this related to BootFeatures:

```
2021-02-04T15:43:17,674 | ERROR | activator-1-thread-2 | BootFeaturesInstaller            | 11 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.2.1 | Error installing boot features
org.apache.felix.resolver.reason.ReasonException: Unable to resolve root: missing requirement [root] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=ssh; type=karaf.feature; version="[4.3.1.SNAPSHOT,4.3.1.SNAPSHOT]"; filter:="(&(osgi.identity=ssh)(type=karaf.feature)(version>=4.3.1.SNAPSHOT)(version<=4.3.1.SNAPSHOT))" [caused by: Unable to resolve ssh/4.3.1.SNAPSHOT: missing requirement [ssh/4.3.1.SNAPSHOT] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=org.apache.karaf.shell.ssh; type=osgi.bundle; version="[4.3.1.SNAPSHOT,4.3.1.SNAPSHOT]"; resolution:=mandatory [caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.karaf.shell.ssh/4.3.1.SNAPSHOT: missing requirement [org.apache.karaf.shell.ssh/4.3.1.SNAPSHOT] osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.karaf.jaas.boot.principal)(version>=4.3.0)(!(version>=5.0.0)))" [caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.karaf.jaas.boot/4.3.1.SNAPSHOT: missing requirement [org.apache.karaf.jaas.boot/4.3.1.SNAPSHOT] osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.9.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))"]]]
```

The error always looks similar although the name of the feature that gives the error is different every time (for example kar and ssh), so it seems that all the BootFeatures are failing and one at random just shows the error first. It seems as if something has changed from 4.2.0.M1 to 4.2.0.M2 in how Karaf features are managed.

We use Java 8 and OSGi 6. Besides that, we use Gradle as a build system and the Aether library (org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn) to handle Maven artifactory/packages resolution.

This is the content of our org.apache.karaf.features.cfg file:

```
featuresRepositories = \
    mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/framework/4.2.0.M2/xml/features, \
    mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/spring/4.2.0.M2/xml/features, \
    mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/standard/4.2.0.M2/xml/features, \
    mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/enterprise/4.2.0.M2/xml/features, \
    mvn:org.apache.activemq/activemq-karaf/5.16.1/xml/features, \
    mvn:org.apache.cxf.karaf/apache-cxf/3.2.7/xml/features, \
    mvn:org.apache.cxf.dosgi/cxf-dosgi/2.3.0/xml/features, \
    mvn:org.ops4j.pax.jdbc/pax-jdbc-features/1.4.5/xml/features, \
    file:/opt/data/features/feature.xml

featuresBoot = \
    (instance, \
    package, \
    log, \
    ssh, \
    aries-blueprint, \
    framework, \
    system, \
    eventadmin, \
    feature, \
    shell, \
    management, \
    service, \
    jaas, \
    shell-compat, \
    deployer, \
    diagnostic, \
    wrap, \
    bundle, \
    config, \
    kar, \
    jndi, \
    jdbc, \
    transaction, \
    pax-jdbc-config, \
    pax-jdbc-pool-common, \
    pax-jdbc-postgresql, \
    pax-jdbc-pool-c3p0, \
    cxf-core, \
    cxf-jaxrs, \
    cxf-jaxws, \
    cxf-dosgi-provider-rs, \
    cxf-dosgi-provider-ws, \
    activemq-broker-noweb), \
    (local_bundle_1, ..., local_bundle_N)

featuresBootAsynchronous=false
```

Does anyone have any idea about what could be the cause of these errors after upgrading from 4.2.0.M1 to 4.2.0.M2?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Karaf is resolving the most current version of the ssh feature for you. To correct, add blacklist entries for the versions that are showing up in the log

file: etc/org.apache.karaf.features.xml

```
<blacklistedRepositories>
    ...
    <repository>mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/standard/4.3.1-SNAPSHOT/xml/features</repository>  
    ...
</blacklistedRepositories>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I forgot to add that in our org.apache.karaf.features.cfg file we also have featuresRepositories referencing 4.2.0.M2, for example:

featuresRepositories = \
    ...
    mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/standard/4.2.0.M2/xml/features, \
    ...

Adding entries with 4.3.1-SNAPSHOT to blacklistedRepositories as well unfortunately did not fix the error (or change it).

Comment: To update from the previous reply, we found about the org.apache.karaf.features.xml file, and added the blacklistedRepositories entries there, along with a `featureProcessing=org.apache.karaf.features.xml` line in org.apache.karaf.features.cfg file, but we are still getting the same error.

Comment: You shouldn't mix Karaf feature versions from the runtime version. Those features are essentially what get karaf to boot.

Comment: @MattPavlovich sorry, what do you mean with mixing the Karaf "feature versions from the runtime version"? We define which features to boot (featuresBoot) and which repositories to have the same versions (featuresRepositories) in the .cfg file -- just added a new .xml file as suggested to block specific repositories. Is there something obvious we are doing wrong here? We are scanning all Karaf documentation but cannot get this back to load again -- and upgrading to 4.2.4 or 4.2.9 produce other errors (osgi.ee == 9.0), even when using the Apache Karaf official Docker images and configuration.